# Laravel only show model if many to many relationship conditional is met?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have a model “Category” and a model “Post” with a many-to-many relationship.

Basically I output Categories somewhere and I want to have this type of pseudo output;

- If any posts that belong to a Category have the “hidden” attribute set to true, then don’t return this Category. (So even if this Category has 100 posts, if even one of them has “hidden” as true on it, don’t return the category.

Here is what I have tried so far but it would seem it only hides the category if ALL Posts are marked as hidden. If even one of them has “hidden” false it shows even if the other 99 are true. Which is quite the inverse of what I want to happen.

```
Category::latest()->whereHas('posts', function ($query) { 
    return $query->where('hidden', false);
})->get();
```

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flip your condition. Your current query is "all categories that have a post that is not hidden." You want "all categories that don't have a post that is hidden."

```
Category::latest()->whereDoesntHave('posts', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('hidden', true);
})->get();
```